# Reading Hadoop sequence file in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

How to read Hadoop sequence file in Flink? I hit multiple issues with the approach below.

I have:

```
DataSource<String> source = env.readFile(new SequenceFileInputFormat(config), filePath);
```

and

```
public static class SequenceFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<String> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = HadoopUtils.getHadoopConfiguration(configuration);
        logger.info("Initializing:"+filePath);
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path hadoopPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(filePath);

        try {
            reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(hadoopPath.getFileSystem(config), hadoopPath, config);
            key = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getKeyClass(), config);
            value = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(reader.getValueClass(), config);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("sequence file creation failed.", e);
        }
    }
```

}

One of the issues: Could not read the user code wrapper: SequenceFileInputFormat.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get an `InputFormat`, you can call `ExecutionEnvironment.createInput(<input format>)` to create your `DataSource`.

For `SequenceFile`s, the type of the data is always `Tuple2<key, value>`, so you have to use a map function to convert to whatever type you're trying to read.

I use this code to read a `SequenceFile` that contains Cascading Tuples...

```
Job job = Job.getInstance();
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(directory));
env.createInput(HadoopInputs.createHadoopInput(new SequenceFileInputFormat<Tuple, Tuple>(), Tuple.class, Tuple.class, job);
```